# T-SQL view is "optimized" but I don't understand why

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, view

I'm struggling with some sort of auto-optimization when creating a view in TSQL.
The optimization is done both when using the Designer and when using CREATE VIEW.

The output is equal, but I don't understand why it's done.

Can anyone please explain me why this is optimized / why the lower one is better:

```
[...]
WHERE
   today.statusId = 7
   AND yesterday.cardId IS NULL
   AND NOT (
      today.name LIKE 'TEST_%'
      AND today.department LIKE 'T_%'
   )
```

gets optimized into the following

```
[...]
WHERE (
   today.statusId = 7
   AND yesterday.cardId IS NULL
   AND NOT (today.name LIKE 'TEST_%')
)
OR (
   today.statusId = 7
   AND yesterday.cardId IS NULL
   AND NOT (today.department LIKE 'T_%')
)
```

Isn't the second where clause forcing the view to check *statusId* and *cardId* two times no matter of their value? While the first allows it to abort as soon as *statusId* is 6 (e.g.)

Also in the first one the parentheses part can abort as soon as one value is FALSE.

This behavior also does not change when the inner parentheses contain like 20 values. The optimizer will create 20 blocks checking over and over again the values of *statusId* and *cardId*...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The designer just rearranges the predicates into something it can easily show in a grid. It does not try and optimize it.

Comment: Ah okay. When I open the view in designer and then save it, will it replace the original where clause with the one he showed for better "grid visibility"?

Comment: Yes, I presume that's the reason. To facilitate visual editing of predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual designers do not try to optimize your code ever.

Don't use them unless you are prepared to put up with them mangling your formatting and rewriting your queries in this manner.

SQL Server does not guarantee short circuit evaluation in any case but certainly this type of rewrite can act as a pessimisization. Especially if one of the predicates involves a sub query the rewritten form could end up significantly more expensive.

Presumably the reason for the rewrite is just so it can present them easily in a grid and allow editing of points at individual grid intersections - or so you can select the whole column and delete.

[image]

Comment: In my view no code ever should be written for production using the designers.